# Firebase added data automatically being deleted

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to add data to an arbitrary path in Firebase real-time database with the Javascript SDK.

All rules are public, so permissions shouldn't be an issue. (read = true, write = true)

Here's my code so far, for the addition of data:

```
function writeUserData(user, taskId, email, password, status) {
  firebase.database().ref('users/' + user + '/tasks-status/' + taskId).set({
    email: email,
    password : password,
    status: status,
  });
}
```

Current project architecture is like this:

```js
{
  "roles" : {
    "UID" : "owner"
  },
  "topics" : ["bio"],
  "users" : {
    "mffUzP5wtBRhOHTVAhGctAUHsa72" : {
      "credits" : -5
    },
    "qfh75zQbIfe8ooAWAB3rbcz4MBQ2" : {
      "credits" : 5
    }
  }
}
```

And I want to programmatically add a child `tasks-status` to the users/UID for each user, and three more children to that one. Ideally, the `tasks-status` node will stay, and later requests will just add the unique `TaskID` node (`mffUzP5wtBRhOHTVAhGctAUHsa721`).

Example:

```
"users" : {
"mffUzP5wtBRhOHTVAhGctAUHsa72" : {
  "credits" : -5,
  "tasks-status" : {
    "mffUzP5wtBRhOHTVAhGctAUHsa721" : {
      "email": EMAIL,
      "password": PASSWORD,
      "status": STATUS
    }
  }
},
```

But for some reason, the set adds the data to the database, but it's highlighted red and automatically removed. In addition, I found that other child nodes of users/UID were also deleted. Also, just wanted to note that I'm not using this for authentication, I'm already familiar and using Firebase Auth.

I've read over the docs about set/update and can't seem to find an answer.

Here's a picture of what I mean, the red is the data that I want to add but is subsequently deleted

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you also have a Cloud Functions database trigger that's doing something in response to your addition of data?

Comment: @DougStevenson No I don't, but I think its because I'm including the write function in a for loop, and it's getting called at the same time, so it might be getting over written.